# Platform to test different versions of outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

We're developing an outlook addin, and the problem I have is that I can not test it on other versions than my current outlook 2013. I've tried to look for AWS images with MS Office in order to test on them, but found none.

Is there a service or a platform that will enable me to run virtual machines with different Windows and Outlook versions?

Comment: I'm  not sure why sad-without-friends people chose to down vote and close this question, as it complies with this scope category: `software tools commonly used by programmers` outlined by stackoverflow. I need a software or tool to test my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own VMs for testing the add-in. There is no such platform or service which provides different versions of MS Office pre-installed on machines.